# Owl-Carousel oversizing images when initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, owl-carousel

I'm having a strange problem when trying to load an owl carousel with AngularJS.

I create all my slides with the following ng-repeat:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="newsCarousel" banner-container>
    <img class="img-fluid" ng-src="{{banner.URL}}"
         ng-repeat="banner in vm.banners" banner-card>
</div>
```

And then initialize the carousel with these directives:

```
app.directive('bannerCard', function ($timeout){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        if(scope.$last)
            return $timeout(function(){
                scope.$emit('LastBannerRendered');
            });
    };
});
app.directive('bannerContainer', function ($timeout){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        $timeout(function(){
            scope.$on('LastBannerRendered', function(event){
                $('#newsCarousel').owlCarousel({
                    autoplay: true,
                    loop:true,
                    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                    items: 1,
                    nav: true,
                    dots: false,
                    navText : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"]
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I've done this multiple times so far (there are 2 other carousels in the same page done like this and working 100% fine) however this specific one doesn't seem to be working properly, problem is that when initialized the slides get a height of over 2000px, an outrageous amount which ruins the overall view.

When I initialize the carousel through the console it doesn't become overly large, but it doesn't have the overflow:hidden and thus all slides are shown one next to the other.

What am I missing here that's causing this specific carousel to behave like this?

To add some more details: The images load with the correct size initially and I can see them for about a second, it's after that that some style is applied that gives them this size.

Comment: Did you load `jquery.js` before `angular.js` as recommended by the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#overview)?

Comment: @georgeawg sorry for the delayed response, but yes I am.

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not occour in my below example, it could be to due to some property of owl carousel being set incorrectly, you could also set the `height` of the main carousel to your desired height by using inline styles.

I have made some corrections to your directive, you can ignore them if you want, please check my example and implement it to your code.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  this.banners = [{
    URL: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"
  }, {
    URL: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"
  }, {
    URL: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x151"
  }, {
    URL: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x152"
  }, {
    URL: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x153"
  }, {
    URL: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x154"
  }, {
    URL: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x155"
  }];
  this.owl1 = {
    navigation: true,
    slideSpeed: 300,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    singleItem: true,
    transitionStyle: 'fade'
  };
  this.owl2 = {
    autoplay: true,
    loop: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    items: 1,
    nav: true,
    dots: false,
    navText: ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"]
  };
});
app.directive('bannerCard', function($timeout) {
  return {
  restrict: 'A',
  controller: 'MyController',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    if (scope.$last)
      element.parent().owlCarousel(ctrl[attrs.bannerCard]);
  }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.transitions.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController as vm' ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="newsCarousel" style="width:350px">
    <img class="slide" ng-src="{{banner.URL}}" ng-repeat="banner in vm.banners" banner-card="owl1">
  </div>
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="newsCarousel">
    <img class="slide" ng-src="{{banner.URL}}" ng-repeat="banner in vm.banners" banner-card="owl2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it also doens't happen to me when I do it on a separate local project. I've managed to fix it by adding a width of 100vw and a max height, but now I get a small overflow to the right

Comment: @Danyx Guess you can solve the overflow by setting `height` to `auto` and ensuring the images are of same dimensions, if you face issues share my a JSfiddle with the issue

Comment: Since it's a minimal issue and there's no reason to have a horizontal scroll I simply solved it by adding a `overflow-y: hidden`. Thank you, I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @Danyx You're welcome, You can close the ticket by giving the solution!